# JVM Spring Boot Actuator metrics and JVM memory calculation from Linux

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, observability

I'm monitoring a Spring Boot application through actuator metrics.
Actuator endpoints reports these metrics:

```
jvm memory used: 362MB
jvm memory committed: 485MB
jvm memory max: 548MB
```

Using `top` linux command I see that the memory used from JVM is around 673 MB.

[image]

So, we have a delta of 125MB from jvm memory max and memory used reported by `top`.
Anyone can explain me this behaviour?